# opencart 2.3 version registry error

Tags: opencart

```
 //init controllers:
ob_start();
  require_once("index.php");
  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


if(isset($_GET['import_id'])){
  require_once('model/tool/profi_import.php');
  $importClass = new ModelToolProfiImport($registry);



  $import_id = (int)$_GET['import_id'];
  $import_data = $importClass->getImport($import_id);

  if(isset($_GET['part'])){
    $parts = htmlspecialchars($_GET['part']);
  }else{
    $parts = '1_1';
  }
  $parts = explode("_",$parts);
  $actual_part = $parts[0]-1;
  $total_parts = $parts[1];
```

I have an like this import file.
But, 2.3 opencart version "Undefined variable: registry" give an error.
I need to change the which code. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: No, my question is different.

Comment: Nope, if you had read the answers, you would know what the problem is, it is because ``$registry`` was never defined therefore display an error because you try to access it.